# Translate recaptcha errors? Magento 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9.3.8, recaptcha

The following piece of code implements error messages for recaptcha. The location is `app/code/local/Magecomp/Recaptcha/Model/Observer.php`

```
public function Customercreate($observer)
{

    try {

        if (Mage::helper('recaptcha/data')->showOnRegister()) {
             $g_response = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('g-recaptcha-response');
            if (isset($g_response) && !empty($g_response)):
                if (!(Mage::helper('recaptcha')->Validate_captcha($g_response))):
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.123');
                    $url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() : Mage::getUrl();
                    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                    exit;
                endif;
            else:
                $observer->getEvent()->setData(null);
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.456');
                $url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() : Mage::getUrl();
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                exit;
            endif;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log("Captcha Error :" . $e->getMessage(), null, "recaptcha.log");
    }
}
```

How could I translate the texts "Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.123"  and "Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.456" into another languages? I know that modifying core files is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a translated string (or both) in the Magecomp Recaptcha Module translation file (should be `app/locale/[your_LANG]/Magecomp_Recaptcha.csv`) if there is one.

The translated string to add to the translation file for the italian language could be:

```
"Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.123","Si prega di cliccare sul reCAPTCHA box.123"
"Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.456","Si prega di cliccare sul reCAPTCHA box.456"
```

Then you have to edit the code in this way:

```
public function Customercreate($observer)
{

    try {

        if (Mage::helper('recaptcha/data')->showOnRegister()) {
             $g_response = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('g-recaptcha-response');
            if (isset($g_response) && !empty($g_response)):
                if (!(Mage::helper('recaptcha')->Validate_captcha($g_response))):

                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('recaptcha/data')->__('Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.123'));

                    $url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() : Mage::getUrl();
                    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                    exit;
                endif;
            else:
                $observer->getEvent()->setData(null);

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('recaptcha/data')->__('Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.456'));

                $url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() : Mage::getUrl();
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                exit;
            endif;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log("Captcha Error :" . $e->getMessage(), null, "recaptcha.log");
    }
}
```

---

I don't know the **Magecomp_Recaptcha** Module, but this module to supports translations need to setup a .csv translation file in the `app/code/local/Magecomp/Recaptcha/etc/config.xml`: look for the `config/frontend/translate` tag in this file. If there is no translation file setup, you need to add it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    [...]
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Magecomp_Recaptcha>
                    <files>
                        <default>Magecomp_Recaptcha.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Magecomp_Recaptcha>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    [...]
</config>
```

Then add the 2 rows below to your `app/locale/[your_LANG]/Magecomp_Recaptcha.csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your root directory and go to the following path:

> /app/locale/de_DE

de_DE its for German you can go to the particular directory as per your store view.

Here, just open the **Mage_Core.csv** file and you can write the text like below example:

```
 "Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.123","Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.456"
```

Then flush your cache and check the frontend.

**If you still face issue then try below code:**

Just replace below code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.123');
```

To

```
$errorMessage = Mage::helper('core')->__('Please click on the reCAPTCHA box.123');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($errorMessage);
```

Let me know if you still face an issue?